# MYSQL grouping and filtering a filter

Tags: mysql, database

So I have a Wardrobe table with records of people who owns colored shirts. Like so,

```
================================
| People   |    Shirt          |
================================
| Peter    |    red            |
| Peter    |    green          |
| Peter    |    blue           |
| Peter    |    blue           |
| John     |    red            |
| John     |    green          |
| Kenny    |    yellow         |
| Kenny    |    yellow         |
| Kenny    |    green          |
| Sam      |    yellow         |
| Sam      |    green          |
| Sam      |    purple         |
| Chris    |    red            |
| Chris    |    red            |
================================
```

I need help querying for how many shirt a person has and only has red shirts. This following query is close, but isn't what I want.

```
Select people, count(shirt) from Wardrobe where shirt='red' group by people.
```

The result is

```
===========================
| People   | count(shirt) |
===========================
| Peter    |    1         |
| John     |    1         |
| Chris    |    2         |
==========================
```

The result I want from a query would give me this

```
===========================
| People   | count(shirt) |
===========================
| Chris    |    2         |
==========================
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

UPDATE

Which technique would be better and more efficient if I happen to be joining multiple tables as well with total records in the millions?

Comment: Are you familiar with `EXITS`?

Answer (score 1):

Get the total number of red shirts a person has, compare this with the total number of shirts, so you only return the rows where these are the same.

```
SELECT People, SUM(Shirt = "red") AS redcount
FROM Wardrobe
GROUP BY People
HAVING redcount = COUNT(*)
```

Or just exclude anyone who has non-red shirt:

```
SELECT People, COUNT(*) AS redcount
FROM Wardrobe
WHERE People NOT IN (
    SELECT People
    FROM Wardrobe
    WHERE Shirt != "red")
GROUP BY People
```

Answer (score 1):

Longer version :)

```
select w.people, w.cnt
from (
Select people,count(shirt) as cnt
from Wardrobe 
where shirt = 'red'
group by people) w
join (
  select people, count(shirt) as d_cnt 
  from Wardrobe 
  group by people) t
on w.people = t.people  and w.cnt = t.d_cnt
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to use subquery.

SELECT People, COUNT(*) AS total FROM(SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Wardrobe WHERE shirt='red' GROUP BY People);

Comment: `DISTINCT *` is an oxymoron, and to a rough approximation, you'd never include a GROUP BY clause and a DISTINCT modifier in th same query. And you'd never have `*` and GROUP BY in the same query.